# T-SQL - How can I make a SELECT query with multiple LIKE clauses quicker?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a search function for news articles that looks like this (contains more than 5 search items):

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM NewsArticles
WHERE (headline LIKE '% sustainable %'OR
headline LIKE '% sustainability %' OR
headline LIKE '% conservation %' OR
headline LIKE '% environmental % OR
headline LIKE '% environmentally %') 
OR
(body LIKE '% sustainable %'OR
body LIKE '% sustainability %' OR
body LIKE '% conservation %' OR
body LIKE '% environmental % OR
body LIKE '% environmentally %')
ORDER BY publishDate DESC
```

This query is designed to pull out the top 5 news stories relating to sustainability and sits on my main sustainability homepage. However, it takes a while to run and the page is slow to load. So I'm looking up ways to speed this up. Having so many LIKE clauses seems cumbersome so I've tried something with a JOIN like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchItem (Search varchar(255))

INSERT INTO #SearchItem VALUES
('sustainable'),
('sustainability'),
('conservation'),
('environmental'),
('environmentally')

SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM NewsArticles as n
JOIN #SearchItem as s
ON n.headline COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %' OR 
n.body COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %'
ORDER BY n.publishDate DESC
```

This seems to work very well for performance, but seems to sometimes bring back duplicate articles where one of the search words appears in both the body and the headline (which is often the case). I've tried using the word using 'SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 *' but this gives me an error saying 'The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable'. Is there away of stopping this from bringing back duplicates without doing 2 separate searches and using UNION?

Comment: Why use *?  Do you need the column of ntext type?

Comment: The double `%` in your `like` statements are one of the main culprits... Do you need this information updated in (near) real time? If not, you could have a lookup table with `articleID` (your articles do have an ID of some kind, I assume?) and flags for `is_sustainable`, `is_conservation`, etc. Then, you could have a batch job that would insert new rows into this table, inputting the correct flags via `like` statements. Then, just join against this lookup table and use the appropriate flags.

Comment: I think the problem with the duplicates arises when there is a match on multiple words, not a match or header and body

Comment: UNion is almost always faster than using OR. Or is aperformance killer beyond the performance killer of having a wildcard as the first charcter. Why do you not want to use UNION?

Comment: @Jack Money - it does need to be real time unfortunately. However the articles do have an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get multiple hits on multiple words, you can use the selected ID's as a filter for the actual selection of the articles:

```
Select TOP 5 * 
from NewsArticles 
where ID in (SELECT ID
    FROM NewsArticles as n
    JOIN #SearchItem as s
    ON n.headline COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %' OR 
       n.body COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %'
)
ORDER BY publishDate DESC
```

It should still be reasonably fast (compared to the original query) and duplicate-free.

(as in Rawheiser's response, there is an assumption that an ID field actually exists :))

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing these types of searches, you should use full text search. You need to read up in BOL about how to set this up as it is complicated. However when you have a wildcard as the first character, then SQL server cannot use indexes which is why this is slow.

Comment: What's BOL and what's upas ?

Comment: BOL is Books online which is the SQL Server help. Upas was a typo for up as

Comment: BOL for us means Boots opticians

Answer (score 2):

If there is an news Article key you can use a query to that joins back to itself such as:

```
select top 5 *
from NewsArticles as na
join 
    ( 
        SELECT distinct idNo , publishDate 
        FROM NewsArticles as n
        JOIN #SearchItem as s
        ON n.headline COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %' OR 
        n.body COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %'
    ) as sk
        on sk.idNo = na.idNo
ORDER BY sk.publishDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks but whilst the query worked, it took far too long to run (23 seconds). Still, it was faster than my original :)

Comment: As always is the case with advice - "your mileage may vary".

Answer (score 1):

You could also try Full-Text Search.  Something like

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM NewsArticles 
WHERE CONTAINS((headline,body), 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, sustainable) OR conservation OR FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, environmental)')
```

But, as HLGEM says, it will be important to read up on setting up FTS.  Just creating an index for those two columns may be enough since you are searching for single words, but once you add phrases you want to start editing stop words and breakers and noise words.

Answer (score 0):

I would so something like this

[image]

I'd program an **case insensitive indexing process that would run at nights**, that would:

- parse articles, insert in `SEARCH_TERM` any new word it finds
- insert in `SEARCH_INDEX` a tuple that says that a given article has a given search term
- mark the `NEWS_ARTICLE` as already indexed.
- next run will index only articles tha haven't been idexed

The a sample query can be like this, and would be lighting fast since you will not be using `LIKE`:

```
select
    distinct n.headline
from
    search_item s
    join search_index x on (s.id = x.search_item_id)
    join news_article n on (x.news_article_id = n.id)
where
    s.term in ('sustainable','sustainability','conservation',
               'environmental','environmentally')
```

Later you could create synonyms for search terms and create a view that returns terms with their synonyms, should you want to make more semantic searches in the future.