# Select field on multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently trying to create a query where i want to select rows if one field contains multiple values. I think ill just give you an example:

Database: field="Ground;Lava;Rocks"

Query should be: select where field contains "Ground" and "Rocks".

My first attempt would have been:

```
SELECT * FROM TerrainLayer WHERE tags LIKE '%Ground%' AND tags LIKE '%Rocks%';
```

Would this be an acceptable solution or are the better (more efficient) ways to achieve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you have multiple values in a single field?

Comment: @CL Because the field contains tags associated with that texture layer and there can be 1-n tags associated with a layer, there is no fixed number and id like to avoid to create another table just to map tags and layers.

Comment: If you're only looking for a couple of tags at a time it shouldn't be too bad. However, if you're looking for multiple tags you could end up having performance issues. I ran into this and got a solution in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257357/t-sql-how-can-i-make-a-select-query-with-multiple-like-clauses-quicker

Comment: @sr28 Yes, its a database that just serves as a data backend for an application, not a server. There are usually 3-4 tags per layer and the user queries 1-2 tags, so i guess it might be ok. But ill have a look at the posting you have linked.

Comment: @Cromon -  you wouldn't need the actual answer given in the question as this deals with a slightly different issue (avoid getting duplicates). You would just need to alter my query (using the JOIN) to only JOIN on 1 thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TerrainLayer WHERE tags LIKE '%Ground%Rocks%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of this too but saw the problem if id for example have stored it as "Rocks;Ground;Lava" but just realized i can simply enforce an alphabetical ordering of the values in the field and the query then this works.

Comment: you can add an `OR tags LIKE '%Rocks%Ground%'`

Comment: @Cromon it means there will be no order followed while inserting that field?

Comment: @Siva There wasnt so far, but its no problem to get that ordering done from now on, i just havent tought about it yet

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should also work, and if you have multiple LIKE clauses should be a little more efficient:

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchItem (Search varchar(255))

INSERT INTO #SearchItem VALUES
('Ground'),
('Rocks'),
('Whatever')

SELECT *
FROM TerrainLayer as t
JOIN #SearchItem as s
ON t.tags COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %'
```

For SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE SearchItem (Search  varchar(255))

INSERT INTO SearchItem VALUES
('Ground'),
('Rocks'),
('Whatever')

SELECT *
FROM TerrainLayer as t
JOIN #SearchItem as s
ON t.tags LIKE '% ' + s.Search + ' %'
```

From what I tested a JOIN like this will be quicker. Obviously, you wouldn't need to manually populate the #SearchItem table like this.

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax.

Comment: @CL. it's valid SQL syntax though.

Comment: Are you claiming that identifiers beginning with `#` and `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` are allowed by the SQL standard?

Comment: @CL. perhaps 'valid' is the wrong word. It seems to work for me though. However, I'd be interested to know how you would re-write this to turn it into valid SQL. I'm assuming you wouldn't use a temp table for example, but declare a table instead.

Comment: This question was for SQLite, so I'd use a [temporary table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), and drop the COLLATE.